# How to define default style of a custom View without using a custom theme?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

My goal is to set an implicit style to a custom Android view.

The View class' 3-argument constructor allows providing the desired default style resource.

```
public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
}
```

I would like to apply the following style by default.

```
<style name="MyWidgetLibrary.MyCustomView">
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <!-- more items... -->
</style>
```

However, defStyle must be an attribute. In fact, I would like to be able to do the following, by directly referencing a style; not an attribute.

```
public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    this(context, attrs, R.style.MyWidgetLibrary_MyCustomView);
}
```

This does not work.

Using an attribute to reference the desired style has the following drawback : it is necessary to set a custom theme so that the attribute can be linked to a style.

How can I apply a default style to the custom View without having to set a custom theme to the application? For instance, I would like to make my custom view usable as part of a library and not require the users to set a different theme just to have the desired default attributes applied.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. My Application depends on multiple libraries adding different functionalities to the app. I also would like to supply views from those libraries with a default style wihtout referencing the theme. Because the theme can only be inherited from one library.